# How to setState when withRepeat isFinished

Tags: react-native, react-native-reanimated-v2

I'm trying to setState inside withRepeat callback to show the button when the animations isFinished but the app closes. How can I update the state based on animation end?

```
  const [showBtn, setShowBtn] = React.useState(false);
  
  // ...

  React.useEffect(() => {
    circle.value = withRepeat(
      withSequence(
        withTiming(1, {
          duration: 4000,
        }),
        withTiming(1, {
          duration: 2000,
        }),
        withTiming(0, {
          duration: 4000,
        })
      ),
      2,
      false,
      (isFinished) => {
        setShowBtn(true); // <- app closes
      }
    );
  }, [showBtn]);

  return (
    {showBtn && (
      <Button onPress={() => {
        circle.value = 0;
        setShowBtn(false);
      }}>Restart</Button>
    )}
  )
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer, I did tried this before but didn't work, so I took another look at the [reanimated 2 docs about runOnJs](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/threading/runOnJS/#remarks)

Instead of using seState inside runOnJs, I created a function and then called runOnJs(updateShowBtn)();

Updated code:

```
const updateShowBtn = () => {
  setShowBtn(true);
};

...

(isFinished) => {
  if (isFinished) {
    runOnJS(updateShowBtn)();
  }
}
```